# How to print inside map function

Tags: rust

I want to know the value of an parameter inside map for debugging purposes.
I expected something like this to work but it doesn't.

```
let result = (0..5)
    .flat_map(|x| (0..=x - 1).map(move |y| (y, x)))
    .map(|(x, y)| println!("{:?}", x) input[x] + input[y])
    .collect::<Vec<i32>>();
```

Comment: It's not valid syntax. Try `.map(|(x, y)| { println!("{:?}", x); input[x] + input[y] })`

Comment: Consider using [`Iterator::inspect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.inspect) for this purpose. It is much more convenient :)

Answer (score 3):

Just create a new scope with braces (`{}`) inside the clusure:

```rust
|(x, y)| {
    println!("{:?}", x);
    input[x] + input[y]
}
```

As per your example:

```rust
fn main() {
    let input: Vec<_> = (0..100).collect();
    let _result = (0..5)
        .flat_map(|x| (0..x).map(move |y| (y, x)))
        .map(|(x, y)| {
            println!("{:?}", x);
            input[x] + input[y]
        })
        .collect::<Vec<i32>>();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b0d66ea56d66d69e2c3c9aab55bbcdda)